# Is using T to separate date and time inconsistent with RFC3339?

Tags: postgresql, datetime, rfc3339

[In the documentation for date/time type in Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html), it says:

> ISO 8601 specifies the use of uppercase letter T to separate the date and time. PostgreSQL accepts that format on input, but on output it uses a space rather than T, as shown above. This is for readability and for consistency with RFC 3339 as well as some other database systems.

However, I cannot find that part in [RFC3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339).
Can anybody help me?

Comment: The note in section 5.6… (Search the document for "space".)

Answer (score 3):

[Section 5.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#section-5.6)

```
date-time       = full-date "T" full-time

      NOTE: Per [ABNF] and ISO8601, the "T" and "Z" characters in this
      syntax may alternatively be lower case "t" or "z" respectively.

      This date/time format may be used in some environments or contexts
      that distinguish between the upper- and lower-case letters 'A'-'Z'
      and 'a'-'z' (e.g. XML).  Specifications that use this format in
      such environments MAY further limit the date/time syntax so that
      the letters 'T' and 'Z' used in the date/time syntax must always
      be upper case.  Applications that generate this format SHOULD use
      upper case letters.

      NOTE: ISO 8601 defines date and time separated by "T".
      Applications using this syntax may choose, for the sake of
      readability, to specify a full-date and full-time separated by
      (say) a space character.
```

Comment: Hmmm - that seems to say that one *may* choose to use a space and not, as the PostgreSQL documentation seems to suggest, required for compatibility with the RFC.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: On ISO you may omit "T", but not on RFC. RFC choose a simpler syntax (a subset of ISO), in order to make thing simpler, and less bug on software (about special cases)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Then it's actually the other way around, and PostgreSQL violates the RFC? I don't think so, see the note.

Comment: Note: RFC3999 is not a standard about date times (and appendixes have, but a proposal how new standard should do, to avoid confusion. PostgreSQL just use ISO. Appendix A has some extra information about differences.